# Rails 4.1 enums and simple form: how to translate them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, simple-form, rails-i18n

While normale `collection` inputs can be easily translated

```
f.input :sex, collection: [:male, :female]
```

using this structure

```
simple_form:
  options:
    profile:
      sex:
        male: Männlich
        female: Weiblich
```

it doesn't seem to be possible to translate the new Rails 4.1 enum features.

I tried to translate

```
f.input :sex, collection: f.object.class.sexes
```

like this:

```
simple_form:
  options:
    profile:
      sex:
        '0': Männlich
        '1': Weiblich
```

But this doesn't work. Is this a missing feature of simple form?

Comment: I added an issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1063

Answer (score 4):

I've just faced the same problem.
Problem is the `simple_form` supports only symbols as keys for translation, and `rails` `enum` has strings as keys like `{"male" => 0, "female" => 0}`.

But I figured out small workaround. Please see [my gist here](https://gist.github.com/ShPakvel/3ccffcc6138f73b84804).

Comment: Thanks for this hint. As explained in the issue, Rails enums are only meant for internal use, so you shouldn't have them in forms, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend to have a look at the following gem: [enum_help](https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help)
It's filling the gap with [Enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)